EF Core 8 - how to represent SQL Server query?
I am new to using EF Core and I am having trouble representing a query with it. I have this T-SQL query which I am having trouble representing with EF Core 8.
We are using database-first approach and I can't change the SQL Server tables. In red_listing_items there is no column which represents the all_article_groups.art_group as a navigation property.
This is the query:
SELECT rli.param5,
       rli.article_number AS "BAN",
       rli.short_text     AS "NAME",
       rli.param8         AS "Optional SKU Group",
       rli.param9         AS "Optional SKU Group Target",
       ag1.description    AS "BRAND NAME",
       ag2.description    AS "CONTAINERSIZE",
       ag3.description    AS "CONTAINERTYPE",
       ag4.description    AS "FLAVOUR",
       ag5.description    AS "PACK SIZE IN ASSORTMENTS"
FROM   phoenix.red_listing_items rli
       INNER JOIN phoenix.red_list_mapping rlm
               ON rlm.listing_id = rli.listing_id
       INNER JOIN phoenix.red_listing_headers rlh
               ON rlh.listing_id = rli.listing_id
       INNER JOIN phoenix.all_article_groups ag1
              ON ag1.prc_group = rli.param1
                 AND ag1.art_group = 1
       INNER JOIN phoenix.all_article_groups ag2
              ON ag2.prc_group = rli.param2
                 AND ag2.art_group = 4
       INNER JOIN phoenix.all_article_groups ag3
              ON ag3.prc_group = rli.param3
                 AND ag3.art_group = 3
       INNER JOIN phoenix.all_article_groups ag4
              ON ag4.prc_group = rli.param4
                 AND ag4.art_group = 2
       INNER JOIN phoenix.all_article_groups ag5
              ON ag5.prc_group = rli.param5
                 AND ag5.art_group = 5
WHERE  rlm.pos_id = 'RD94000011'
       AND rlm.question_id = 'STANDARD 1'
       AND type = 1 

These are my entity configurations:
namespace SFA.AdminTool.Domain.Entities.PhoenixSchema;

public class RedListingItem : BaseEntity<long>
{
    public long ArticleNumber { get; set; }

    public string ListingId { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Product { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Param1 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Param2 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Param3 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Param4 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Param5 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Param6 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string ParamPos { get; set; } = null!;

    public decimal Weight { get; set; }

    public string? ShortText { get; set; }
    public string? Param7 { get; set; }
    public string? Param8 { get; set; }
    public string? Param9 { get; set; }
    public string? Param10 { get; set; }
    public string? Param11 { get; set; }
    public string? Param12 { get; set; }
    public string? Param13 { get; set; }
    public string? Param14 { get; set; }

    public string AllArticleGroup1PrcGroup { get; set; }
    public string AllArticleGroup2PrcGroup { get; set; }
    public string AllArticleGroup3PrcGroup { get; set; }
    public string AllArticleGroup4PrcGroup { get; set; }
    public string AllArticleGroup5PrcGroup { get; set; }

    public AllArticleGroup? AllArticleGroup1 { get; set; }
    public AllArticleGroup? AllArticleGroup2 { get; set; }
    public AllArticleGroup? AllArticleGroup3 { get; set; }
    public AllArticleGroup? AllArticleGroup4 { get; set; }
    public AllArticleGroup? AllArticleGroup5 { get; set; }

    public virtual RedListingHeader Listing { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual AllArticleGroup AllArticleGroup { get; set; } = null!;
}

namespace SFA.AdminTool.Domain.Entities.PhoenixSchema;

public class AllArticleGroup : BaseEntity<long>
{
    public string PrcGroup { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;

    public ICollection<RedListingItem> RedListingItems1 { get; set; } = new List<RedListingItem>();
    public ICollection<RedListingItem> RedListingItems2 { get; set; } = new List<RedListingItem>();
    public ICollection<RedListingItem> RedListingItems3 { get; set; } = new List<RedListingItem>();
    public ICollection<RedListingItem> RedListingItems4 { get; set; } = new List<RedListingItem>();
    public ICollection<RedListingItem> RedListingItems5 { get; set; } = new List<RedListingItem>();
}

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using SFA.AdminTool.Domain.Entities.PhoenixSchema;

namespace SFA.AdminTool.Database.Configurations.PhoenixSchemaConfigs;

public class RedListingItemConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<RedListingItem>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<RedListingItem> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("RED_LISTING_ITEMS_PK");

        entity.ToTable("RED_LISTING_ITEMS", "PHOENIX");

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.ArticleNumber, "IX_RED_LISTING_ITEMS_ARTICLE_NUMBER_LISTING_ID");

        entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.ListingId, e.Product, e.Param1, e.Param2, e.Param3, e.Param4, e.Param5, e.Param6 }, "RED_LISTING_BASE_UK").IsUnique();

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.ListingId, "RED_LIST_ITEMS_HEAD_FK_I");

        entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.ArticleNumber, e.ShortText, e.Weight, e.ParamPos, e.Param14, e.Param13, e.Param12, e.Param11, e.Param10, e.Param9, e.Param8, e.Param7, e.Param6, e.Param5, e.Param4, e.Param3, e.Param2, e.Param1, e.Product, e.ListingId }, "SAPSORT$3255_I");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("(NEXT VALUE FOR [PHOENIX].[RED_LISTING_ITEMS_SEQ])")
            .HasColumnType("numeric(15, 0)")
            .HasColumnName("ID");
        entity.Property(e => e.ArticleNumber)
            .HasColumnType("numeric(10, 0)")
            .HasColumnName("ARTICLE_NUMBER");
        entity.Property(e => e.ListingId)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("LISTING_ID");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param1)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM1");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param10)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM10");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param11)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM11");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param12)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM12");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param13)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM13");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param14)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM14");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param2)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM2");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param3)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM3");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param4)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM4");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param5)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM5");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param6)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM6");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param7)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM7");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param8)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM8");
        entity.Property(e => e.Param9)
            .HasMaxLength(90)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM9");
        entity.Property(e => e.ParamPos)
            .HasMaxLength(9)
            .HasColumnName("PARAM_POS");
        entity.Property(e => e.Product)
            .HasMaxLength(120)
            .HasColumnName("PRODUCT");
        entity.Property(e => e.ShortText)
            .HasMaxLength(120)
            .HasColumnName("SHORT_TEXT");
        entity.Property(e => e.Weight)
            .HasColumnType("numeric(5, 2)")
            .HasColumnName("WEIGHT");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.AllArticleGroup1).WithMany(p => p.RedListingItems1)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Param1)
            .HasPrincipalKey(v=>v.PrcGroup);
        entity.HasOne(d => d.AllArticleGroup2).WithMany(p => p.RedListingItems2)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Param2)
            .HasPrincipalKey(v => v.PrcGroup);
        entity.HasOne(d => d.AllArticleGroup3).WithMany(p => p.RedListingItems3)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Param3)
            .HasPrincipalKey(v => v.PrcGroup);
        entity.HasOne(d => d.AllArticleGroup4).WithMany(p => p.RedListingItems4)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Param4)
            .HasPrincipalKey(v => v.PrcGroup);
        entity.HasOne(d => d.AllArticleGroup5).WithMany(p => p.RedListingItems5)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Param5)
            .HasPrincipalKey(v => v.PrcGroup);
    }
}

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using SFA.AdminTool.Domain.Entities.PhoenixSchema;

namespace SFA.AdminTool.Database.Configurations.PhoenixSchemaConfigs;

public class AllArticleGroupConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AllArticleGroup>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AllArticleGroup> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Id, e.PrcGroup })
            .HasName("ALL_ARTICLE_GROUPS_PK");

        entity.ToTable("ALL_ARTICLE_GROUPS", "PHOENIX");

        entity.HasIndex(e => new
        {
            e.Id,
            e.PrcGroup,
            e.Description
        }, "ALL_ARTICLE_GROUPS_SAPALLARTICLEGROUP_sort_i")
            .IsDescending(false, false, true);

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.Id, "ALL_ARTICLE_GROUP_ARTG_I")
            .HasFillFactor(100);

        entity.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnType("numeric(10, 0)")
            .HasColumnName("ART_GROUP");

        entity.Property(e => e.PrcGroup)
            .HasMaxLength(3)
            .HasColumnName("PRC_GROUP");

        entity.Property(e => e.Description)
            .HasMaxLength(40)
            .HasColumnName("DESCRIPTION");
    }
}

I am having trouble representing the AND part where the art_group =1 ; 2; 3; 4; 5
       INNER JOIN phoenix.all_article_groups ag1
              ON ag1.prc_group = rli.param1
                 AND ag1.art_group = 1
       INNER JOIN phoenix.all_article_groups ag2
              ON ag2.prc_group = rli.param2
                 AND ag2.art_group = 4
       INNER JOIN phoenix.all_article_groups ag3
              ON ag3.prc_group = rli.param3
                 AND ag3.art_group = 3
       INNER JOIN phoenix.all_article_groups ag4
              ON ag4.prc_group = rli.param4
                 AND ag4.art_group = 2
       INNER JOIN phoenix.all_article_groups ag5
              ON ag5.prc_group = rli.param5
                 AND ag5.art_group = 5

I am using the AutoMapper ProjectTo extension method through a repository:
    public async Task<List<RedAssortmentAnswerVm?>> GetRedAssortmentAnswers(long activityId, string? posId, string? questionId)
    {

        var assortments = await redListingItemRepository.GetAllByAsync<RedAssortmentAnswerVm>(RedListingItemsFilterBy(posId, questionId), mapper.ConfigurationProvider);

        return assortments;
    }

    public Task<List<TProjectTo>> GetAllByAsync<TProjectTo>(Expression<Func<TEntity?, bool>> predicate, IConfigurationProvider provider, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return AsQueryable().Where(predicate).OrderBy(v => v!.Id).ProjectTo<TProjectTo>(provider).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity?> AsQueryable() 
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
    }

this is the AutoMapper configuration:
        private void RedListingType1Config()
        {
            CreateMap<RedListingItem, RedAssortmentAnswerVm>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BAN, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                    src.ArticleNumber))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                    src.ShortText))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OptionalSkuGroup, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                    src.Param8))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OptionalSkuGroupTarget, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                    src.Param9))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BrandName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                    src.AllArticleGroup1.Description))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ContainerSize, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                    src.AllArticleGroup2.Description))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ContainerType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                    src.AllArticleGroup3.Description))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Flavour, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                    src.AllArticleGroup4.Description))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.PackSizeInAssortments, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                    src.AllArticleGroup5.Description))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.TypeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                    src.Listing.Type))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ListingId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                    src.Listing.RedListMappings.FirstOrDefault().ListingId));
        }

How can i represent the query with my repository GetAllBy method. I tried using just the AsQueryable() and .Include but still with no luck.
    private static Expression<Func<RedListingItem?, bool>> RedListingItemsFilterBy
        (string? posId, string? questionId)
    {
        return rli => rli.Listing.RedListMappings.Any(lm => lm.RedPos == posId && lm.QuestionId == questionId && lm.Listing.Type == 1) 
        && rli.AllArticleGroup1.Id == 1
        && rli.AllArticleGroup2.Id == 2
        && rli.AllArticleGroup3.Id == 3
        && rli.AllArticleGroup4.Id == 4
        && rli.AllArticleGroup5.Id == 5;
    }

i tried using this expression in the GetAllBy method but it returns 0 rows from DB. If i do not include the AllArticleGroup1 2 3 4 5  .Id = 1 2 3 4 5 it returns 6000 rows and I am expecting only 65 rows based on the results of the raw sql query

You don't. EF is an ORM, not a database driver or query builder. DbContext is a Unit-of-Work and doesn't need to be wrapped in CRUD classes. DbContext  loads an entire graph of related objects. The JOINs are generated by EF itself based on the relations between entities. EF doesn't need AutoMapper, GetAll methods or single-entity "repositories". There's no need for base entities either

You have to forgot about Automapper in this query. Query is simple but requeries SelectMany operator, which makes AM useless.

For anything complex, create a view with your t-sql query and the results of that can be a new entity. That makes the EF side simpler and avoids any internal confusion it may incur.
